# Ladda loading button in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a submit button in my rails form that I would like to change to a spinning loading icon when the user hits submit. My app is using bootstrap so I've followed the example provided [here](http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/).

The rails code for the submit button looks like:

```
<%= content_tag :button, :class => "btn btn-u ladda-button", :type => "submit", :data => { :style => 'expand-left' } do %>
  <span class="ladda-label">Next</span>
  <span class="ladda-spinner"></span>
<% end %>
```

The HTML being rendered looks like:

```
# in <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            Ladda.bind( '.ladda-button' );
        });
</script>

# submit button at the end of my rails form_for
<button class="btn btn-u ladda-button" data-style="expand-left" type="submit">
  <span class="ladda-label">Next</span>
  <span class="ladda-spinner"></span>
</button>
```

I have included ladda.js and spin.js in my assets/javascripts folder. ladda-themeless.css is included in my stylesheets controller.

When I click the next button, the text inside the button changes colour (to a dark grey). Chrome console is now displaying the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function application.js:17884createSpinnerapplication.js:17884instance.start application.js:17577(anonymous function)
```

Comment: @JTG No. This form just completes a basic save function of a local object. However, it does push the data gathered from the form through a 3rd party API via an after_commit call in the model.

Comment: Errors in console?  Can you see if the css/js is being loaded in your browsers development view?

Comment: @JTG There aren't any errors in the chrome console. When I search application.css and application.js in chrome dev tools I do see the files ladda js and css files being loaded.

Comment: Have you tried to make sure spin.js is loaded before ladda.js? That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the

```
Ladda.bind( 'input[type=submit]' );
```

part into $(document).ready wrapper. If you use Turbolinks, use:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function(){
  Ladda.bind('.ladda-button');
});
```

Comment: I've wrapped my original JS in a document ready wrapper and I'm still receiving the same result. I've updated my question with your suggestion in the #head JS section.

Comment: I've updated answer to bind to class instead of button.

Comment: I've bound the class. I'll update my q with the code. However, when I click the button the colour of the text changes within the button (step in the right direction). I am getting an error in console now (added in my question). Thanks for continuing to try and help. Should I be putting the minified version of the js in my assets folder instead of the full sized ones?

Comment: It is not dependent on full/minified source. Do you require it in your application.js? Also if you remove that script code, and execute `Ladda.bind('.ladda-button');` manually from Chrome console, will it raise that error?

Comment: When I run the command I get an undefined error. It also creates a span in the button with a spinner class.

Comment: Then it should be a problem with Ladda. Is Ladda defined? (so call `Ladda` without anything and see if it returns a function or undefined).